# HighCharts SetExtremes not working

Tags: ios, highcharts

Here is my sample code in Objective C. The setExtremes is not set with the min/max that we pass in. Any help is appreciated!

```
HIEvents *events = [[HIEvents alloc] init];

NSString *jScript =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"function () { this.chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(%@,%@);}",min,max];

events.load = [[HIFunction alloc] initWithFunction:jScript];
chart.events = events;
```

Answer (score -1):

Was able to fix this:

```
HIEvents *events = [[HIEvents alloc] init];

NSString *jScript =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"function () { var series = this.series[0]; series.xAxis.setExtremes(%f, %f, true, true); }", min, max];

events.load = [[HIFunction alloc] initWithFunction:jScript];
chart.events = events;
```